# Realm not writing correctly

Tags: ios, swift, cocos2d-iphone, realm

I've been trying to use Realm to create a db for my cocos2d game, but can't figure out some problem. I'm using Realm Objective-C 0.92.3 (https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/) since I need my game to work on iOS 7 or later.

I've been using some small code to write and read but somehow it isn't working.

```
     let realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()
     var tempo = EnemyDB()
     tempo.damage = 7
     realm.beginWriteTransaction()
     realm.addObject(tempo)
     realm.commitWriteTransaction()
     var temp = EnemyDB.allObjects()
```

Somehow this is returning empty object (temp  = RLMResults! Unevaluated query on    0x00007f954708a070), does anyone see any problem?

Thank you for any help

EDIT:

```
import Foundation

class EnemyDB : RLMObject {
     var damage : Int!
}
```

Comment: Can you add your `EnemyDB` code?

Comment: Added if it is in any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to explicitly set a default value for the value of `damage` in `EnemyDB`.

Try changing it to this, and let me know if that works!

```
class EnemyDB : RLMObject {
     var damage: Int = 0
}
```

Comment: That was one of the problems, it helped me after duplicating this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25198509/querying-in-realm-using-swift, and the final problem was that sometimes you have to delete old DB that was created with different objects, so you can read out new values.

Comment: Glad I could help! Yeah, if Realm generates a .realm file and you subsequently modify the object's properties, you'll need to perform a migration in order to update the .realm to the new object schema. But for development purposes, it's easier to just delete the old .realm file. :)

Answer (score 0):

this occurred with me and finally I figured out that my query string was not complete, by printing my predicate to the console as below.

**Objective-C:**

```
NSLog(@"%@",searchPredicate);
```

**Swift:**

```
print(\(searchPredicate)
```

It printed "SELF.message CONTAINS nil".

`nil` was the issue here. I fixed it and problem was gone.

Check for the same issue in your case.